# How to reset the system variable: CLASSPATH for JAVA?

Tags: java, classpath, java-home

I am using Windows 7 and I modified the CLASSPATH and now, in the cmd window, my JAVA cannot work properly: it can compile classes properly, but when I try to run it using:`"java CLASS"`, the system always says `"Could not find or load main class"`

The reset 2 system variables related to Java are:

1. JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`
2. Path: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin`
3. CLASSPATH: `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib` (Updated version, still not working...)

Now, how could I reset my CLASSPATH?

My test code:

```
public class a {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("abc");
 }
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a `\bin` and certainly not `;` at the end of `JAVA_HOME`. And you didn't show what the value of `CLASSPATH` actually was.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you for your reply...I updated the 3 variables, and restart the cmd window, but still not working.

Comment: One more thing: are you sure the class  that you are running actually *has* a proper `main` method?

Answer (score 1):

Use Your **CLASSPATH**

```
.;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\lib
```

Use ".;" . is refer to this and will find your class.

Your JAVA_HOME

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
```

and Your Path

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;
```

Use this ... this is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to update the system variables like this, but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set path for your java
Follow these steps:

1- Go to My computer

2- Properties

3- Advanced System Settings

4- Environment Variables

5- Select path in the 2nd **LOWER LIST BOX**

6- click on edit

Now first go to c:program files/java/jdk1.*/bin/
and copy this path at the end of your path

PATH: c://whatever/whatever
APPEND: c://whatever/whatever***;//c://program files/java/jdk/bin***

Answer (score 0):

You set your `JAVA_HOME` incorrectly. The `JAVA_HOME` home **always** should be like this -

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31;
```

**Note**:  the `JAVA_HOME` is set up to just before `bin` directory.

I think modifying the `JAVA_HOME` like this would solve your problem. The `PATH` added here seems OK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the variables, but not working. How about the CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 0):

On windows. Worked for me.put in   terminal
"set CLASSPATH="
And my java program start executed in command prompt .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).